# Database configuration for Drupal

Tags: drupal-6

I am try to installing **Drupal-6.2.4** on **XAMP**. I created db named drupal_6_2_4 and when installation process reaches at **Database configuration** step it does not create tables into supplied db and just reload the page.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps check the Apache logs?

Comment: have you modified settings.php file @sites/default/settings.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to edit the settings.php file, putting in my database information manually.  Just look for this line:

```
$db_url = mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename;
```

And change the username, password and databasename parts.

Then return to the Database Configuration screen, enter the information again and continue.  The correct database information will be read from the settings file and the configuration will continue to the next step.

And one think more before try this first try to add the user permissions to the folder, **/sites/default** may be it solve the problem.

Happy hunting!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the file in below path

sites/all/default/setting.php

There you can edit the below things manually

Host
Database name
Username
Password